# Replacing a column of DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a datebase and a `DataGridView` that i bind by the request `SELECT idUser, nameUser, idFunction FROM dbo.Users`.

- table_**Users** {idUser, nameUser, idFunction}
- table_**Functions** {idFunction, nameFunction}

How can I replace the colum "idFunction" of the grid view by "nameFunction"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a join linking the two tables based on idFunction

> SELECT idUser, nameUser, f.nameFunction FROM dbo.Users u
>   Inner Join table_Functions f on f.idFunction = u.idFunction

More information on joins can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)